# Late '70s robot anime with a male protagonist who says "punchu cheezu" as he transforms into a robot head

Tags: story-identification, anime

Best estimate was 1978-1980 (just when I was starting school, while living in Japan). The male protagonist (teen?) would jump off of a cliff, punch his fists together, and spin forward in a tight curl.

To my anglicized ears, it sounded like he said "punchu cheezu" at this point and he transformed into a robot head. A female (sister? Girlfriend?) would fly up in some sort of craft and fire out the rest of the robot's parts from her aircraft.

I don't even know if it was in English, but at that age I didn't care. My sister and I just called the show punch-u cheezu.

Anyone remember this one?

Answer (score 28):

Sounds like this is probably *[Kotetsu Jeeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Jeeg)* (AKA *Steel Jeeg*), an anime series which ran for 46 episodes, and originally aired from 1975-1976. A sequel series, [Koutetsushin Jeeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotetsushin_Jeeg), was released in 2007.

From the Wikipedia page:

> Steel Jeeg is formed by combining the parts released by the Big Shooter jet, piloted by Prof. Shiba's young assistant, Miwa Uzuki. Hiroshi Shiba becomes the head of Steel Jeeg by bumping his fists together.

And here's a short YouTube clip showing the transformation:

Listening to the audio in the clip, it sounds to me like the main character shouts "Kotetsu Jeeg", the name of the robot and the show.

Comment: Thank you. That is it. Over 40 years ago

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting arrows. :-)

Comment: With the greatest respect to the show's creators, _PUNCHU CHEEZU_ might have been even better.

Comment: Somehow I think my 5 year old ears misheard the Japanese :D

Comment: @G F  - Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting arrows.